# Mocking a 3rd Party class

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I would like to mock a class (i.e. with RhinoMocks) for which I don't have access to the code for (like say [ManagementObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx) or [ManagementObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection_members.aspx)) and for which methods/properties I am interested in

- isn't virtual
- isn't defined in an interface which the class implements

The way that I have been getting around this is to implement wrappers for these classes and to mock (and use) these wrappers.

Are there alternatives to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Java, you could use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). It may mock classes without an interface.